# Inverse of pyspark.sql.functions greatest

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there an inverse to the function greatest? 
Something to get the min of multiple columns?

If there is not, do you know any other way to find it than using udf functions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [inverse is](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=least#pyspark.sql.functions.least):

> `pyspark.sql.functions.least(*cols)`
>
> Returns the least value of the list of column names, skipping null values. This function takes at least 2 parameters. It will return null iff all parameters are null.
>
> ```
> >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3)], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
> >>> df.select(least(df.a, df.b, df.c).alias("least")).collect()
> [Row(least=1)]
> ```